# Regex excluding LineBreak and Spaces

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

This is the first time that i have really needed to write any RegEx, but I'm fairly lost. I need to find items that match the example below, where anything in *'s could change. There are also records that are similar but without the linebreak and space that i do not wish to select. The number of spaces can vary. If anyone can help that would be great! Below is an example of what i wish to search for:

---

```
inspect *DX-DATA-EX1*(*0000411*:*0000002*)
                                        converting E-NUMB to A-NUMB
```

---

Sorry for the confusion if my initial post was too vague (first post here, wasn't sure what to include) so i have the above line. I need the following (pseudo code):

```
*anything*(*anything*)*newline* converting E-NUMB to A-NUMB
```

Hopefully that is slightly more helpful? :$
I'm just trying to do a search of a text file in Notepad++ using the RegEx option.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: Also what language are you trying to use this regex in?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your input string should match this regex:

```
^[^\(]*\([^\)]*\)(\r\n?|\n\r?)+ +converting E-NUMB to A-NUMB$
```

Explanation:

```
^      The beginning of the string
[^\(]* Any characters at all (including new line) that are not an opening `(`
\(     An opening `(`, escaped so that it is treated at its real value
[^\)]* Any characters that are not a closing `)`
\)     A closing `)`, escaped so that it is treated at its real value
(\r\n?|\n\r?)+  Any combination of carriage return and line feed, one or more times
 +     At least one space 
converting E-NUMB to A-NUMB  Exactly these characters
$      The end of the string
```

[Online tester](https://regex101.com/r/bR7nV9/1)